# Python/pandas: data frame from series of dict: optimization

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4

I have a pandas Series of dictionnaries, and I want to convert it to a data frame with the same index.

The only way I found is to pass through the `to_dict` method of the series, which is not very efficient because it goes back to pure python mode instead of numpy/pandas/cython.

Do you have suggestions for a better approach?

Thanks a lot.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> flagInfoSeries = pd.Series(({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20}))
>>> flagInfoSeries
0      {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1    {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
dtype: object
>>> pd.DataFrame(flagInfoSeries.to_dict()).T
    a   b
0   1   2
1  10  20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

flagInfoSeries = pd.Series(({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20}))
print flagInfoSeries
0      {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}
1    {u'a': 10, u'b': 20}
dtype: object

print pd.DataFrame(flagInfoSeries.to_dict()).T
    a   b
0   1   2
1  10  20

print pd.DataFrame([x for x in flagInfoSeries])
    a   b
0   1   2
1  10  20
```

**Timing**:

```
In [203]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(flagInfoSeries.to_dict()).T
The slowest run took 4.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 554 µs per loop

In [204]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([x for x in flagInfoSeries])
The slowest run took 5.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 361 µs per loop

In [209]: %timeit flagInfoSeries.apply(lambda dict: pd.Series(dict))
The slowest run took 4.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 751 µs per loop
```

EDIT:

If you need keep index, try add `index=flagInfoSeries.index` to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print pd.DataFrame([x for x in flagInfoSeries], index=flagInfoSeries.index)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [257]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([x for x in flagInfoSeries], index=flagInfoSeries.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 350 µs per loop
```

**Sample**:

```
import pandas as pd

flagInfoSeries = pd.Series(({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20}))
flagInfoSeries.index = [2,8]
print flagInfoSeries
2      {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}
8    {u'a': 10, u'b': 20}

print pd.DataFrame(flagInfoSeries.to_dict()).T
    a   b
2   1   2
8  10  20

print pd.DataFrame([x for x in flagInfoSeries], index=flagInfoSeries.index)
    a   b
2   1   2
8  10  20
```

Comment: Yep, so your computer is faster, but your code still wins :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want add comparing in my PC. :)

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. Indeed, there are improvements in terms of performances ... but the indexes are not kept: the list comprehension gives the a list `[{mydict}, ...]`, without the index, while the `to_dict` gives a dictionnary of `{index: {mydict}, ...}`. I think I'll keep it like this for now.

Comment: Solution was modified, please check it.

Comment: It's even faster with the index!

Comment: Yes, first I was surprised too, but I think `DataFrame` constructor take index, not count, so it is faster.

Comment: Great! It works perfectly and it is fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great comparison! Anyway, I think using `pd.DataFrame(flagInfoSeries.to_numpy().tolist())` is even faster than your proposal (which would be even more visible when running for longer series, not just two items).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.json_normalize(flagInfoSeries)`.

Answer (score 0):

This avoids `to_dict`, but `apply` could be slow too:

```
flagInfoSeries.apply(lambda dict: pd.Series(dict))
```

---

**Edit**: I see that [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35600418/5276797) has added timing comparisons. Here is mine:

```
%timeit flagInfoSeries.apply(lambda dict: pd.Series(dict))
1000 loops, best of 3: 935 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, but indeed, apply is slow.